# My String and StringBuilder are not displaying output in console

Tags: java, regex, string, stringbuilder

I am parsing textual data from one single PDF page. I am able to apply regex(referred one of the stackoverflow solutions) and get just the text which I am looking for. The problem is, appending the parsed string to StringBuilder at each intermittent iteration shows data in console while SOPing, but not the final value[the whole textual data of that particular page]. I have tried following things:

1) 
    Go to Window > Preferences > Run/Debug > Console
    Uncheck "Limit Console Output"

2) Trying to write the same string in a text file.

3) checked the length of the string which shows 3746( which means there is lots of data in it).

package com.PDFReaderApp2;

```
private static ReentrantLock counterLock = new ReentrantLock(true);
private static Pattern PARAGRAPH = Pattern.compile("\\s*^\\s*$\\s*", Pattern.MULTILINE);
private static Pattern MULTISPACE = Pattern.compile("\\s+");
private static boolean flag = false;
private static BufferedWriter writer = null;

public static StringBuilder processString2(String args) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    String x = args;
    x = compactLines(x);
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\((.*?)\\)").matcher(x);
    while (m.find()) {
        x = m.group(1);
        builder = builder.append(x);
        x = builder.toString();
        // x= x.replaceAll(System.lineSeparator(), " ");
        System.out.println("-->>  " + x);
    }

    System.out.println("is x empty?: " + x.length());
    x = builder.toString();

    return builder;
}

public static String compactLines(String source) {
    return Stream.of(PARAGRAPH.split(source)).map(para -> MULTISPACE.matcher(para).replaceAll(" "))
            .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
}

public void readThisPage(int pageNum) throws IOException {
    writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\bhard\\Desktop\\output.txt", true));
    InputStream inputStream = document.getPages().get(pageNum).getContents();
    String text = new String();
    text = IOUtils.toString(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
    System.out.println(text);
    StringBuilder mofo = processString2(text);
    text = mofo.toString();
    System.out.println("is text empty?: " + text.length());
    writer.write(text);
    System.out.println("text of " + pageNum + "\n " + mofo);

}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InvalidPasswordException, IOException {

    ReadPDFFile2 pdf2 = new ReadPDFFile2();
    pdf2.setFileInstance("E:\\E Books\\Novels and Story books\\Adler-Mortimer-How-To-Read-A-Book.pdf",
            "Adler-Mortimer-How-To-Read-A-Book.pdf");
    pdf2.readThisPage(3);

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Call the close() or flush() method on writer and it should show the output.
Make sure to cleanup the resources.

Comment: awesome. Thanks a lot. It dumps the output into the file now, but still doesn't show anything in the console. I don't have problem with that as long as it lets me perform further string operations on the phantom String object's data, which I shall be able to given the data in the file, right??

Comment: I would suggest to put a debugger and step into the function processString2. There could be issue with data and pattern matching.